# a problem in fractional calculus

Tags: calculus, analysis, fractional-calculus

One of the early applications of fractional calculus is the tautochrone problem set up by Abel in the integral form or its fractional derivative one. i wish to know its solution.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautochrone_curve#Abel.27s_solution

Answer (score 3):

I am attaching to you the solution as an image.

[image]

[image]